# Issue in Firefox 3.6 with ajax call to PHP

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Seems that a site I made for fun does not like to work in firefox 3.6 ... can't really figure out what is causing the issue tho, once i open firebug it works fine...

here is the link http://samsaccone.com/apad_scroller/

any ideas would be appreciated,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have console.log statements @ line# 48 and line# 59 (`console.log(spot);` and

```
console.log("set up called");)
```

console.log is not available when FireBug is not enabled and hence the script fails.

Remove those lines and your page should work fine.

Comment: ah epic you win, sorry I forgot about those :)